# Is there a way to remove sub-document from object without passing the parentId?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, subdocument

Is there a way to remove sub-document from object without passing the parentId?
So I have a document which looks like this:

```
name: {
  type: [String],
  trim: true,
  required: [true, 'Please add your name']
},
experience: [
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: [true, 'Please add an experience title']
    }
  }
],
```

Each of this document can have several objects in the experience array.

Adding and updating has been easy for me because I usually just need to pass the Id of the parent document.

Now I would like to delete any object of said experience array by proving only its id...not the parentId.

Hopefull this code can help explain what I'm looking for:

```
  const resume = await Resume.findByIdAndUpdate(
    {
      // _id: req.params.id, // <=== is the parent id...
      experience: { _id: req.params.exp_id }
    },
    {
      $pull: { experience: { _id: req.params.exp_id } }
    },
    {
      new: true,
      runValidators: true
    }
  );
```

You can see in the code above that I passed the _id of the parent document which if I continue this way, it works great but for my needs I need to only pass the _id of the subdocument.

Is that actually possible?

Comment: I think all you need to do is use `update` or `updateOne` instead of `findByIdAndUpdate`.

Comment: So, there is a exp_id in `experience` sub-document? Like: experience: [
  {exp_id: String,
    title: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: [true, 'Please add an experience title']
    }
  }
]

Comment: Actually......no, there's no exp_id in the document. Each sub-document is generated with an _id by mongoDB, so I only pass the exp_id which is just the name of a parameter(not a field of the sub-document) that matches with the _id of the sub-doc. Did I explain myself? lol

Comment: @ippi i will try that tomorrow morning to see if that works. Its already late now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, using `{}` searches in all parent documents.

```
parent.updateMany({}, {$pull, {children: {_id: id}}})
```

Please also make sure the child `_id` is a string and not `ObjectId`. If that's the case you need to first convert your string to `ObjectId`